# Filtering WPF TreeView without using Observable Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I am filling my `TreeView` from MySQL database. So I don't have classes for each of them.  I use `HierarchicalDataTemplate`s to construct TreeView and I have three levels. I want to filter the first levels comparing the included `TextBlock`'s Text and user input. How can I filter without using `ObservableCollection`? (I tried to use `ICollectionView`, but I failed.)

```
Source = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(FileTreeView.ItemsSource);

        this.Source.Filter = item =>
            {
                TreeViewItem vitem = item as TreeViewItem;

                if (vitem == null) return false;

                foreach (object items in vitem.Items)
                {
                    vitem.ApplyTemplate();

                    TreeViewItem firstlevel = vitem.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as TreeViewItem;

                    UIElement element = GetChildControl(firstlevel, "fem_title");

                    if (element != null)
                    {
                        TextBlock txt = (TextBlock)element;

                        return (txt.Text.Contains(title.SelectedValue.ToString()));
                    }
                }

                return false;
```

It throws an "NotSupportedException".

How I populate the TreeView:

```
private DataSet FillDataGrid()

    {

        try

        {

            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();

            con.ConnectionString = ConString;

            con.Open();



            MySqlDataAdapter femda = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM fem_table", con);

            MySqlDataAdapter versionda = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM version_table", con);

            MySqlDataAdapter fileda = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM file_table", con);



            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            femda.Fill(ds, "fem_table");

            versionda.Fill(ds, "version_table");

            fileda.Fill(ds, "file_table");



            DataRelation dr = new DataRelation("DataRelationship_fem_version",

                ds.Tables["fem_table"].Columns["fem_guid"],

                ds.Tables["version_table"].Columns["fem_table_fem_guid"],

                true);



            DataRelation dr2 = new DataRelation("DataRelationship_version_file",

                ds.Tables["version_table"].Columns["version_id"],

                ds.Tables["file_table"].Columns["version_table_version_id"],

                true);



            dr.Nested = true;

            ds.Relations.Add(dr);

            ds.Relations.Add(dr2);

            return ds;



        }

        catch (Exception ex)

        { throw new Exception(ex.Message); }

    }



  private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {

        this.FileTreeView.DataContext = FillDataGrid();

     }
```

Comment: Please provide a code sample with your attempt using `ICollectionView`.

Comment: I edited to provide the code how I tried to use ICollectionView

Comment: Thank you, thought it doesn't clear things up to me. Could you please set breakpoint on line `TreeViewItem vitem = item as TreeViewItem;` and tell me what item's type is?

Comment: Filter method is problematic I think. It gives error "Specified method is not supported.". So "item doesn't exist in the current content" it says.

Answer (score 1):

Filter works with underlying data, not with UIElements. Since you don't use classes to represent TreeViewItem and populate them just with string, then your item is actually a string.
This works:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<string> Test = new List<string>() { "test", "someothertext" };
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        treeView.ItemsSource = Test;
        var Source = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(treeView.ItemsSource);
        string search_text = "test";
        Source.Filter = item =>
        {
            return item.ToString().Contains(search_text);
        };
    }
}
```

I didn't understand if you use multiple textboxes to filter, but if you dont you should just give a name to one and use its text like

```
string search_text = txtbox.Text;
```

Comment: I was trying just for one, if it worked I would try for all the textboxes. I populate my treeview with a dataset which is constructed by the mysql tables, so `ItemsSource`is a dataset.

Comment: Could you provide code on how you populate treeview items?